# Ienumerable<KeyValuePair<T, string>> as a datasource . how to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have a generic method that returns

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, string>>
```

but i expect the T to be an integer. How can i bind this to combo box in an asp.net web form application?

Currently i get an exepction when i bind the result to my combobox. my method is be

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, string>> GetData<T>(IEnumerable<global::Dev.DAL.pets> st, Func<global::Dev.DAL.pets, T> getData)
    {
        var filtered = st.Select(a => new  { Id = getData(a), Code = Convert.ToInt32(getData(a)).ConvertToCode() });
        foreach(var v in filtered )
            yield return new KeyValuePair<T, string>(v.Id, v.Code );



    }
```

Comment: If you expect `T` to be an integer, why not make it an integer instead of being generic?

Comment: Excellent question, this is what i'm currently doing. I'm learning to use generic and this probably a confusion moment on my journey. Thanks your for the comment.

Comment: Could you post the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: here is the exception beeing thrown:

Exception message: DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Code'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your markup (or code) is setting the DataTextField/DataValueField properties of the DropDownList incorrectly.

Try setting the DataTextField to `"Value"` and the DataValueField to `"Key"`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ... DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key" ...
```

Comment: well, i have actually not taken this explicit step after calling databind. Could this explain the error? The exception is thrown at the statement

Comment: The part of your exception `does not contain a property with the name 'Code'`, leads me to believe that your DropDownList markup or code specifies the DataTextField or DataValueField to be `"Code"`. The databinding routine is attempting to find a property named `Code` in the datasource, however it does not exist and an exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, actually i did in the markup. I did set DataTexField to be Code. so yes, i did.

Comment: Try modifying your markup as detailed in my answer above, that should resolve the issue.

Comment: hers i my markup   <asp:ListBox Width="100px" ID="lsb_id" AutoPostBack="true"
                            DataTextField="Code" DataValueField="Id" Runat="server" Height="70" 
                            SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                            />  and i'm receiving the exact same exception... Does the code make any sense in the first place?